# Siblings survive an attack in a religious war and are helped by siblings of a different species

Tags: story-identification, novel, religion

I remember getting a book at an airport once (part of a trilogy) on my way to a vacation.

I really want to read it again so any help would be appreciated.

The book is about a kingdom devided by religion. The Northern kingdoms are banished because they believe in a “road of blood”?

The Southern kingdoms are attacked a few hundred years later and its most Northern province is destroyed and occupied. A castle of the “baron/earl” in the North is sacked and only a brother and a sister escape (children of the “baron/earl”). They are helped by a sibling pair of a different species.

There is also a halfbreed human that gets left to die and in the process he becomes a very powerful mage. The halfbreed is the one who helps the Norsemen to attack.

Comment: *When* did you read it?  *What* species were the helpers? Are there any other fantastic elements that could help ID the milieu, such as dragons or elves?

Comment: no dragons.. read the first book after 2008 second i got in 2010 or possiblt 2011. Dont remember what the species are called. They are woodland creatures and the female is a warrior with a staff/spear.

Comment: It's a longshot, as it does have dragons and published a few years before 2008, but possibly "The Runes of War", from the Runespell trilogy. http://www.janewelch.com/runes_of_war.htm (Link has prologue and chapter one).

Comment: nope!! sont remember dragons. i do remember that the Norsemen had some kind of "special forces" Ravens or something that were very good warriors and that the book 2 inrtoduces a third sibling pair. They are both part of this Special Force! The Female gets controled by the halfbreed that has by now become a very powerfull mage! I also remember that the Norse destroy a damn in the barony thay capture and that as a cause an entire town is flooded.

Comment: Can you remember anything that isn't story based? I.e. Character names, place names, world names? Or indeed *anything* unique about that particular story. Even creatures or weapons. Events are not much use unless the person reading them has read the book themselves. Also: It seems that "road of blood" is probably not the exact phrase used in the book, unfortunately.

Comment: yea have spent days trawling amazon, wikipedia and other places to find something related to theese books. Unfortunatley names are totaly blank. only "place" i do remember is "the breaking stone" a stone where the halfbreed gets left to die but he survives and becomes a powerfull mage in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found it!!

it wasn't the "blood road" search that did it but "black road"!

That got me Google pictures and as soon as i saw the cover i knew this was it!

Brian Ruckley’s trilogy, called the “Godless World,” is made up of the books Winterbirth, Bloodheir, and Fall of Thanes.

Now i need to find copies of thees books again! They have kept me glued to the pages from start to finish. Brian likes to keep it interesting from start to finish. Specially in this trilogy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[Blood Red Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Red_Road)* by Moira Young?

> Saba lives with her father (her mother is dead), brother Lugh, and
>   younger sister Emmi in a wasteland where laws do not exist. Half a
>   year after Saba and Lugh turned eighteen, four cloaked horsemen show
>   up, kill the father, and kidnap Lugh. The novel revolves around Saba's
>   quest to find and rescue her brother, with whom she has a close
>   relationship.
>
> Saba does not like her younger sister Emmi as she blames Emmi for
>   their mother's death (who died giving birth to Emmi) and tries to
>   leave her with a family friend named Mercy, but Emmi follows Saba. The
>   two are captured by a couple who force Saba to fight in the Colosseum
>   for a man known as the Cage Master. The couple, Mr. and Mrs. Pinch,
>   keep Saba fighting by abusing and threatening the life of Emmi. Saba
>   and her sister eventually escape from Hopetown, the place where the
>   Colosseum is located, with a fellow fighter named Jack and a group of
>   female warriors known as the Free Hawks.
>
> As the story progresses, Saba learns that Mr. and Mrs. Pinch are
>   actually the parents of a king who uses an addictive drug to control
>   people. This same king is the one who sent the four cloaked horsemen,
>   known as the Tonton, to kidnap Lugh. Not only are more plans made to
>   rescue Lugh, but more conflict ensues and a romance develops between
>   Saba and Jack.

Comment: Nope... Nothing you write matches with the book I remember.
The North tribes capturing the castle of the southern kingdoms northern barony, the sibling pair escaping the ransacking of the castle, the halfbreed that becomes a mage, the damn that gets destroyed and floods an entire town killing thousands...